# How do I access a desktop shared by Netmeeting (on Windows 2000)?

Tags: windows-2000

I have got a legacy application that still requires Windows 2000 which is running in a virtual machine. For security reasons that machine only has access to a virtual network on the host that runs it.

I want to access the desktop of that VM using Netmeeting desktop sharing. I have set it up and enabled it

[image: Netmeeting Desktop Sharing]

But I am at a loss how I now can connect to this service from another VM running Windows 8.1, which has access to the same internal network. I tried  the Remote Desktop Client but could not get a connection. Pinging the Win 2000 VM works fine, so there is no network problem.

Any hints?

(Warning: Googling Netmeeting gives a lot of hits that are not safe for work)

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time that I used netmeeting or 2000. But netmeeting can only connect to netmeeting. So you need the netmeeting client on both the clients to connect. Netmeeting is no longer supported by Microsoft so no supported client exists for 8.1. The RDP client won't work as netmeeting is not RDP. If this is 2000 server OS then you can install terminal service in remote admin mode and use RDP on 8.1. Otherwise, you will need a different remote tool like VNC or something that still support 2000